# HTML not executing OnClick script

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, styles

So I have a checkbox on my page which, if clicked, should reveal some hidden content

```
<form onSubmit="return builder()">
Check this to reveal the hidden part <input type="checkbox" name="check" onClick="return show()" />
<div id="hide" style="display:none">hidden part</div>
(...more irrelevant code...)
</form>
```

onClick, it should execute the script below:

```
function show() {
if (document.getElementByName("check").checked) 
{document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "block";}
else 
{document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";}
}
```

but it does not execute it at all, I inserted an alert("hi") and nothing popped up. What do I do wrong?

**Also, please no jQuery.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your function like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="check" onClick="show(this);" />
```

Your function:

```
function show(ref){
 if (ref.checked)
   document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "block";
else 
 document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Aaaah thank you very much! This did the trick for me. (still you've forgot the opening brackets after if and else ;P)

Comment: @user3673616 , when we write single line statements after if or else then we don't need to open the brackets. The brackets are optional if you write a single line statements after if() and else. :D (Happy coding)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `show` function:

```js
function show() {
if (document.getElementsByName("check")[0].checked) 
{document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "block";}
else 
{document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";}
}
```

It is `getElementsByName`, not `getElementByName`.

---

Also, modify your form:

```html
Check this to reveal the hidden part <input type="checkbox" name="check" onClick="show();" />
```

You don't need a `return` for that.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName returns an array with list of tag names, so you need to use document.getElementsByName("check")[0] instead of document.getElementsByName("check"). Check below code..it works.. cheers!

```
<script>
function show() {

if (document.getElementsByName("check")[0].checked) 
{document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "block";}
else 
{document.getElementById("hide").style.display = "none";} 



}


</script>
<form onSubmit="return builder()">
Check this to reveal the hidden part <input type="checkbox" name="check" onClick="return show()" />
<div id="hide" style="display:none">hidden part</div>

</form>

</html>
```